# How to prove convergence of a series that has a recursively defined sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion

I've been banging my head against this one for a couple days ... relatively new to math and physics still, so I'm looking for some help here! This is actually coming out of a problem in a Quantum Mechanics textbook. I'm currently taking Analysis I to give you an idea of where I am in math.

In part of the problem, we are asked to show that the series shown below diverges as $|u|\to 1$, unless $\lambda = l(l+1)$ where $l=0,1,2...$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k u^k$$

The sequence $a_k$ is defined by the recursion relation shown below

$$a_k\frac{(-k(k+1)+\lambda)}{(k+2)(k+1)}=a_{k+2}$$

I've tried comparison test, zero/divergence test, an argument that tries to use the contrapositive of the monotone bounded sequence convergence theorem, and an argument that tries to make use of the fact that the series we're given kind of looks like a geometric series... all to no avail.

Comment: What happens if $\lambda=l(l+1)$? What happens at $k=l$?

Comment: Do you mean $\vert u \vert=1$ or $\vert u \vert \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: If  λ=l(l+1) when k=l, then the series converges because it terminates (the numerator goes to 0), but we are supposed to show that for any case OTHER than that, the series diverges.


@Severin: I think that it would make more sense to |u|=1, but in the problem it is written |u| --> 1 (the professor wrote this problem by hand and is a Physics professor (not Math))

Comment: @logpiy: I gather this series is a solution to  singular-regular second order equation obtained by Frobenius-Fuch's method. Do you care to share that (just for completeness)?

Comment: Wow, thank you guys SO much for these responses! I'm going to move through each of them and will follow-up with any questions. Thank you again for the effort for a total stranger! Much appreciated

Comment: @OliverDíaz In this case the series was given in the prompt, but we ARE covering Frobenius' method in that class (Quantum Mechanics II) right now (I haven't yet read that section so I'm not terribly familiar with it yet), so I wouldn't be surprised if that is how you would arrive at this series. The second order ODE is a modified form of Schrodinger's eqn! I'm happy to share the entire problem prompt if you'd like

Comment: @logpiy: It's all right. I thought that you might have had the second order question that leads to this power series. In any event you have already a handful of solutions. I added mine since I am proselytizing some convergence tests that are rarely taught in Calculus nowadays, the Bertrand test is one I used. This is a type of root test that gives finer results when the ratio test fails.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\lambda = l(l+1)$ and $k = 2q + r$, $ r \in \{0, 1\}$. Then the recurrence relation takes the form

\begin{align*}
a_{2q+r}
&= - \frac{(2q+r-1+l)(2q+r-2-l)}{(2q+r)(2q+r-1)} a_{2(q-1)+r}.
\end{align*}

Repeatedly applying this relation and then applying the Stirling's approximation, we get

\begin{align*}
a_{2q+r}
&= (-1)^q \frac{2^{2q} (q+\frac{r-1+l}{2})_{(q)} (q+\frac{r-2-l}{2})_{(q)} }{(2q+r)!} a_{r} \\
&= (-1)^q C_r \left( \frac{1}{q} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{q^2}\right) \right) \quad \text{as } q \to \infty,
\end{align*}

where $(x)_{(n)} = x(x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), $C_r$ is defined by

$$ C_r = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, a_{r}}{2^r (\frac{r-1+l}{2})! (\frac{r-2-l}{2})! }, $$

and we adopt the convention $\frac{1}{s!} = 0$ for $s \in \{-1, -2, -3, \ldots\}$. Consequently, we obtain the following result:

> **Conclusion.** Let $|u| = 1$. For each $r \in \{0, 1\}$, we consider the series
> $$ \sum_{q=0}^{\infty} a_{2q+r} u^{2q+r}. $$
>
> 1. When $C_r = 0$, the series is eventually terminating, hence it converges absolutely. This condition occurs in each of the following scenarios:
>
>    - $a_r = 0$, or
>    - $l = p - r$ for some *negative odd* integer $p$, or
>    - $l = p + r$ for some *nonnegative even* integer $p$.
>
>    (I will leave the part of rephrasing this condition in terms of $\lambda = l(l+1)$ to others.)
> 2. When $C_r \neq 0$ and $u \notin \{ \pm i \}$, the series converges conditionally by the Dirichlet test.
> 3. When $C_r \neq 0$ and $u \in \{ \pm i \}$, the series diverges by the limit comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Very nice! The case $u=\pm i$ annoyed me a lot, now I can sleep well this night :)

Answer (score 1):

If $\vert u \vert <1$ then the series converges the comparison test (the coefficients $a_k$ are bounded). On the other hand, if $\vert u \vert>1$ the series diverges by the divergence test (the coefficients decay slower than any exponential as we show below). Hence, we are left to consider what happens for $\vert u \vert=1$.

It seems to be false that for $\vert u \vert =1$ the series diverges (for $u\neq \pm i)$. It is unclear to me whether the series converges if $u=\pm i$.

**Warm-up: u=1**

Pick for simplicity $u=1$, then we are interested in the convergence of

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k. $$

To show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges, it is enough to show that both

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}, \quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k+1} $$
converge. I will focus on the first term, the second can be dealt with in a similar fashion.

We will show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$ satisfies the alternating series test and hence converges.

For this we note that

\begin{align*}
\frac{-k(k+1)+\lambda}{(k+2)(k+1)} = \frac{-1-\frac{1}{k}+ \frac{\lambda}{k^2}}{1+\frac{3}{k}+\frac{2}{k^2}}.
\end{align*}
Now we expand the denominator and get
\begin{align*}
\frac{-1-\frac{1}{k}+ \frac{\lambda}{k^2}}{1+\frac{3}{k}+\frac{2}{k^2}}
&= \left( -1-\frac{1}{k}+ \frac{\lambda}{k^2}\right) \left( 1-\frac{3}{k}+O(1/k^2)\right) \\
&= -1 + \frac{2}{k} + O(1/k^2).
\end{align*}

Hence, we get (for $k$ large enough)

$$ \vert a_{k+2} \vert < \vert a_k \vert. $$

Furthermore, we can write for some $K$ large enough

$$ a_{2n+K} = a_K(-1)^n \underbrace{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-\lambda+(K+2j)(K+2j+1)}{(K+2j+2)(K+2j+1)}}_{=: b_{2n+K}}.$$

We have $b_{2n+K}>0$. So the only thing that is left to check is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_{2n+K}=0$. It is a general fact that an infinite product of terms in $(0,1)$ converges to zero iff the series over the logarithms of the factors diverges (see [How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n) and the links therein). In our case we have to deal with

$$ \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left( 1- \frac{2}{j} + O(1/j^2) \right).$$

We check that

$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{j} + O(1/j^2) \right) = \infty $$
as $ \sum_{j=0}^\infty O(1/j^2) $
converges (by the comparison test with $C/j^2$) and the fact that the harmonic series diverges to $+\infty$. Thus,
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_{2n+K} = \prod_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda+(K+2j)(K+2j+1)}{(K+2j+2)(K+2j+1)} = \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{2}{K+2j} + O(1/j^2)\right)= 0.  $$

**General $\vert u \vert =1$ where $u\neq \pm i$:**

For a more general $u\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm i\}$ with $\vert u \vert=1$ we can resort to the Dirichlet test (see [Explanation for the Proof of Dirichlet's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645552/explanation-for-the-proof-of-dirichlets-test)). In our case we have rewrite our series as

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k+K} u^{2k+K} = \sum_{k=1} (-1)^k u^{2k+K} b_{2k+K}. $$
We have already shown that $(b_{2k+K})_{k\geq 1}$ is monotone decreasing and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} b_{2k+K}=0$. Thus, we are left to check that there exists $M>0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \left\vert \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k u^{2k+K} \right\vert \leq M $$
We note that that the series in question is a geometric series and we have (for $u^2\neq -1,$ i.e. $u\neq \pm i$)
$$ \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k u^{2k+K} = u^K \sum_{k=1}^N (-u^2)^k = -u^{K+2} \frac{1-(-u^2)^N}{1+u^2}. $$
Therefore, we have for $\vert u \vert =1$ and $u\neq \pm i$
$$ \left\vert \sum_{j=1}^N (-1)^k u^{2k+K} \right\vert \leq \frac{2}{\vert 1+u^2\vert}. $$
Hence,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} u^{2k} $$
converges by Dirichlet's criterion.

**Special case $u=\pm i$:**

I do not see on the spot whether the series converges in this case. I would assume here it starts to depend on the relation between $a_0$ and $a_1$. Maybe if we choose $a_0$ and $a_1$ in a suitable way we can use again Dirichlet's test with $\vert\sum_{j=1}^N (\pm i)^j \vert \leq \sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Throughout this posting, we assume that $\lambda\notin\{\ell(\ell+1):\ell\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$.
$b_k=a_{2k}$ $c_k=a_{2k-1}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that there is $K$ such that  $b_{k+1}/b_k<0$ and $c_{k+1}/c_k<0$ for all $k\geq K$. Then, the terms of the series $\sum_{k\geq K}b_k$ and $\sum_{k\geq K}c_k$ alternate in sign. For $k\geq K$,
\begin{align}
-\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}=\frac{|b_{k+1}|}{|b_k|} &= \frac{4k^2+2k-\lambda}{4k^2+6k+2}=1-\frac{4k-2-\lambda}{4k^2+6k+2}=1-\frac{1}{k}+O\big(\tfrac1{k^2}\big)\\
-\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}=\frac{|c_{k+1}|}{|c_k|} &= \frac{4k^2-2k-\lambda}{4k^2+2k}=1-\frac{4k-\lambda}{4k^2+2k}=1-\frac{1}{k}+O\big(\tfrac1{k^2}\big)
\end{align}
It follows that $\big|\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}\big|\vee \big|\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}\big|<1$  for $k\geq K$ and so, the sequences $|b_k|$ and $|c_k|$ are eventually monotone decreasing and thus, they converge.

A simple calculation shows that
$$\Big(k\big(1-\frac{|b_{k+1}|}{|b_k|}\big)-1\Big)\log k=\frac{(\lambda-2)k-2}{4k^2+6k+2}\log k\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0<1
$$
and
$$\Big(k\big(1-\frac{|c_{k+1}|}{|c_k|}\big)-1\Big)\log k=\frac{(\lambda-2)k}{4k^2+2k}\log k\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0<1
$$
Thus,   both $\sum_n|b_n|$ and $\sum_n|c_n|$ diverge by [Bertrand's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672275/121671). To consider the possibility of conditional convergence along the circle $|z|=1$, we determine the limits $\lim_k|b_k|$ and $\lim_n|c_k|$.
Notice that
$$\frac{|b_{k+K}|}{|b_K|}=\prod^{k+K-1}_{j=K}\Big(1-\frac1j+ O\big(\frac{1}{j^2}\big)\big)
$$
Since $|b_k|$ converges and $\sum_j\Big(\frac{1}{j}+O\big(\frac{1}{j^2}\big)\Big)=\infty$, it [follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519656/121671) that $\lim_kb_k=0$. The same argument shows that $\lim_kc_k=0$.

Putting things together, we have that   the series $\sum_kz^{2k}b_k$ and $\sum_kz^{2k-1}c_k$ converge absolutely inside the unit disk $|z|<1$, and conditionally for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ (by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)) except for $z\in\{\pm i\}$ (this corresponds to the outcome of Bertrand's test).